# Working with a remote GET request using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on this SMS sending application which use an external service and I use CodeIgniter to build this application.

What I want to do is send a GET request to that SMS service using a URL like this:

http://smsservice.com/sendsms.php?user=sudaraka&msg=hellohello

When my user wants to send a message he will fill a form and when clicked submit, this URL will be created and called without showing it to the application user.

Then the service will give a response with success message with 200 OK and I want to capture it from my application.

I need your help on how to define this process using CodeIgniter.

Comment: For sending sms through url you have to use **urlencode** otherwise only first word of SMS will be sent

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PHP with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). In your case I think this will do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://smsservice.com/sendsms.php?user=sudaraka&msg=hellohello");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option tells curl to save the result of the request in a string instead of printing it directly to the screen. For other options you should check out [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: isn't there any built in CodeIgniter functions to do that? Actually I've gone through the CodeIgniter xmlrpc documentation but it didn't work out well.

Comment: Why would you want to use xmlrpc for a simple GET request? As far as I know there is no build in functionality in CodeIgniter to do the above.

Comment: This is simply because of my lack of knowledge about RPC :/ Thank you, I will try this.